# WPF - Prevent Autoresize of ListBox on new Databinding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout, expand

I currently have a window with a ListBox within in.  The ListBox shows the results from a search.

The problem I currently have is that when a search is performed and enough items are added to the ListBox, the ListBox expands vertically and forces the form to expand vertically as well.

I know I can fix this with a maxheight, but I don't want to limit the size of the form to the user, only to the program at runtime.

Is there a way I can tell the ListBox to not automatically expand or only expand when the user resizes the form?

Comment: This can certainly be done, but it depends on the listbox containers and surrounding elements. You are talking about a form, what is that concretely? You should post a simplified XAML that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies... I've sorted out the problem.  I'd mistakenly set Window.SizeToContent = "Height".

Problem solved.

Comment: I'm glad you found your problem! I suggest you either accept your own answer or vote to have the question deleted? Regards

Comment: Yeah... I have to wait 24 hours though before I can accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in a Grid.  Unless the window is set to automatically size (SizeToContent="..."), then this should work.

```
<Grid>

    <ListBox x:Name="lstSomeData"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

</Grid>
```